# Magento 2.3.1 not loading correct javascript files (tinymce)

Tags: magento2, javascript, wysiwyg, tinymce

I've upgraded from Magento 2.2.6 with Theme Ves Fresh 2. 
I have tried to clean all caches delete static folder and restart Varnish, but had no luck so far.

The errors include:

`GET https://shop.xxxxs.de/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

````
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError 

GET https://shop.xyxxyx.de/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/themes/modern/theme.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) ```

 Uncaught TypeError: b is not a constructor
    at m (tinymce.min.js:13)
    at Object.q [as init] (tinymce.min.js:13)
    at p.<anonymous> (tinymce.min.js:13)
    at Array.<anonymous> (tinymce.min.js:4)
    at b (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at r (tinymce.min.js:4)
    at tinymce.min.js:4
    at HTMLScriptElement.h (tinymce.min.js:4)
````

[image: Errors]

Comment: Did try to run "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f" command? If not then please run this command and let me know if you still have the same issue.

Comment: Did you solved then please let us know here

Comment: It did solve but after some time it still occurring. unless clear Magento cache from admin